# How do I compile mac osx app developed on 64 bit Mac OSX to run on 32 bit?

Tags: xcode, macos

I am writing a program in mac osx mountain lion 10.8 in Objective C/C++ . The machine is 64 bit. 
I am new to mac world coming from windows .Net development and C/C++

GOAL: 
The program has to be compatible with platoform 10.5 mac osx Leopard and onwards both 32bit/64bit.
And the goal is to have single installer/release for  10.5 - 10.8 32bit/64bit

My understanding is (May be I am wrong , please correct me) that If I compile it on 10.8 Lion 64 bit the program will not run on for example on a 10.5 32-bit versions but may run on 10.5 64 bit (ofcourse I have to test it).

Given my platform 10.8 64 bit can I make xcode compile the app for 32bit/64bit and have one release rather than two variations ?

On linux/windows if I compile a 32bit program it will run on 64 bit platforms too, but not the other way around I am not sure how xcode/mac can achieve my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Base SDK to Current version of Mac (ex. 10.7)
Set the Deployment SDK to older version (ex.1.4)

Change Deployment target as :
[image]

Change Base SDK as:[image]

Just above this you will find architectures, you can change them to 32 or 64 as your need

Comment: Thanks for your response, so in my case to be able to target both 32/64 bit platforms I should change architecture to i386 instead of x86_64 ? is that correct ?