# How to easily test cocoa app on different version of mac osx?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a macbook air 2011 version and have 10.8.x installed on it. I used xcode 4.6 to develop an app, I tested it using this machine and worked perfectly fine.

I want my app to support 10.6 (snow leopard) and 10.7 (lion) as well (I set my deployment target to 10.6 and base sdk to 10.7) , so in order to test it, I compiled my app using my macbook (again, 10.8 mountain lion) and copy the app to my other 10.6 machine (hackintosh).

Testing on 10.6 is a pain in the butt, I have learnt a few tricks tried to make the testing easier (ie. implementing redirectConsoleLogToDocumentFolder so that all NSLog will be added to the console.log), however sometimes my app will cause a segmentation fault, which can't be caught by try catch, and I really had no clue what caused the problem.

My questions are:

```
1. how to easily test my app (with ARC enabled) on a 10.6 machine without xcode? I have installed xcode 4.2 on snow leopard, however it doesn't support arc and couldn't compile, even I downloaded the 10.7 sdk and put it into my xcode folder. 

2. are there any other tricks you can share with me, to make the testing on 10.7/10.6 easier?
```

Comment: You mean test cases or testing for compatibility?

Comment: testing for compatibility, make sure my app runs on 10.6 without crashing

Comment: I hope my answer on this question can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548335/how-do-i-compile-mac-osx-app-developed-on-64-bit-mac-osx-to-run-on-32-bit

Comment: And once you are done, there should not be any worry to test for campatibilty

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work in this case. I have already set the deployment target to 10.6, also tried setting the base sdk to 10.7 or 10.8 (latest os x). If I run my app on my 10.8 machine, it works perfectly. Also xcode doesn't show any warning about the compatibility on 10.6/10.7, and I **thought** it should be fine on 10.6, however it wasn't the case. I copied my app to 10.6 machine and I got all different kinds of error (segmentation error, crashed). Looking at the crash report doesn't help much, also couldn't figure out what cause the segmentation error.

Comment: is ur application dependent on some framework that is not available in prior versions?

Comment: my app just use the cocoa.framework and service.management framework (so that it can launch at login), nothing special