# xcode 4.5 target Mac OS 10.7 and 10.6.8

Tags: macos, xcode4.5

I would like to build my App for Mac OS 10.7 and 10.6.8 besides 10.8. It works well for 10.8 but if I change the Deployment Target to 10.7 or 10.6 and want to run it on a Mac with 10.7 or 10.6.8 it crashes right at the start.

Do I have to change more than that? I couldn't find any documentation on that. I added some pictures to show which settings I changed.

Thanks

[image: Settings for 10.7]

[image: Settings for 10.6.8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Base SDK to Current version of Mac (ex. 10.8)

Set the Deployment SDK to older version (ex.10.6)

Comment: I have set the Current SDK to 10.8 (which I am using) and if the Deployment SDK is the same as I have set in my last post I did that as well. I couldn't find a separate setting called Deployment SDK.

Comment: Check this similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548335/how-do-i-compile-mac-osx-app-developed-on-64-bit-mac-osx-to-run-on-32-bit/14549804#14549804)

Comment: I am building it for 64bit since ARC doesn't work with 32bit. could that be a problem?

Comment: I tried a simple program and it works that way. I guess I'm using something in my app thats not conform with 10.6. Now I just need to find what it is or just don't care about 10.6 and 10.7. I thought this kind of stuff should be worked out by apple but apparently not. Thanks anyway